# Trying to identify a mysterious taskbar icon

Tags: windows, icons

Twice in the past fortnight (that I have noticed), a strange icon has appeared in my taskbar. It is red, looks like 'D!' or possibly 'O!' in white text (visually similar to the Filezilla icon), and has 'Broadcaster window' or possibly 'Broadcasting window' in the title. On clicking to examine it, it seemed to be a window with an image (trees maybe?), but it immediately disappeared (hence the vague description). It didn't trip any anti-malware programs, and a full scan with BitDefender and Ad-Aware did not turn up any malware. I can't find anything in the task list that immediately jumped out at me, and no installed programs have a similar icon (apart from Filezilla, as mentioned, and it's not that). It doesn't resemble anything in the system tray. This is on an up to date Windows 7 system.

Google has not helped - even making a fake 'D!' image:

[image]

...and reverse image searching it didn't help. (Ditto for an O! image)

Any help identifying this appreciated, either as a nasty I need to scrub off my system, or a benign thing that I can safely ignore. Many thanks.

UPDATE: have identified it as dingit.tv adware - serves out adverts for games. Malwarebytes apparently good at getting rid of it.

[image: dingit.tv popup]

Comment: Task Manager > Startup tab - does it appear in that list? Alternatively, does Process Explorer shed any light on it's path or attributes?

Comment: Might be brand specific. What brand of computer is this?

Comment: @CharlieRB Dell (Optiplex 9 series). I thought this myself, but before the last fortnight I do not recall seeing this icon at all in the 4 years I've had this PC, and it's my office PC, I use it all day Monday to Friday. Also the other brand-specific things that I dismiss every time I power up don't have red icons.

Comment: @spikey_richie It doesn't appear to be in startup items (although Win 7's startup items list doesn't have icons - will try autoruns), and I couldn't see it in process explorer, although it's long since gone from the taskbar now. (EDIT: icon doesn't appear in autoruns 'everything' tab either)

Comment: Does the icon re-appear after a reboot?

Comment: Try looking in `Control Panel > Notification Area Icons` to see if it shows up there. Might give you a clue what it is.

Comment: @CharlieRB No luck there either. Currently searching my entire C: drive for *.ico to see if it shows up.

Comment: Searching *.exe might show more... but not necessarily as icons can also be stored within dll files.

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the icon in your question? If not, could you get one and even the window/tree thing?

Comment: Not a screenshot (it was gone too quickly for that), but my mock-up of what I recall it looking like that I used for a reverse image search. Will also try an .exe search.

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, there have been several reboots in the time this has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the idea in my other answer didn't work (but is still a good first idea so I'm leaving the answer up), here's another one (and a half).

## Monitoring API Calls

Icons are added to the Windows Notification Area via invocations of the [Shell_Notify Windows API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You could hook into this function and log all uses of it. Get this logger to run before the mysterious icon appears, then check to see which processes invoked it in order to find your culprit.

You can write such a logger yourself, but there are existing utilities for monitoring Windows API calls. A quick search yielded [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825960/wanted-winapi-calls-logger) containing listings for various such utilities.

### Getting the Utility to Run First

For starters, you could try putting it in your startup normally and hoping it'll load first. If that doesn't work you can try replacing Explorer.exe with a program of your own that runs your logger and then runs the real Explorer.exe (just for the sake of solving this issue; switch it back afterwards).

You wouldn't need to worry about it at all if you could replace the actual DLL containing the function (Shell32.dll) with a version that writes to a log and then delegates the invocation to the real function, but I'm not sure Windows will let you do that (it might validate signatures for system DLLs or something for all I know).

## Manually Checking Everything

Another option is to go over **every entry** on the list of running processes and kill each one in turn until the icon disappears (make sure to move your mouse cursor over it after each one for it to refresh). This may seem like an annoying way to go about it, but it may be the easiest one to do after all...

Comment: Logging API calls is an intriguing possibility, and since I've tried everything else and my only other recourse is to blat the machine (which I probably should do anyway to set a good example to my users) I'm going to accept this answer and look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the **notification area customization settings**.

Go into Control Panel and choose the *Appearance and Personalization* category:
[image: Appearance and Personalization]

Then click on *Taskbar and Start Menu*:
[image: Taskbar and Start Menu]

In the window that opens click on the *Customize...* button:
[image: Customize Button]

Now you should see a window that looks like this:
[image: Notification Area Icons]

Look for your mysterious icon there. Hopefully there will be a name next to the icon that will help you figure out what it is.

(There's probably a shorter way to reach this screen, but I don't have Windows 7 installed so I had to search the web for the steps to reach it and the images I used.)

**Edit**: You can check [this page](https://www.howtogeek.com/75510/beginner-how-to-customize-and-tweak-your-system-tray-icons-in-windows-7/) for instructions on how to reach the customization screen in various Windows versions.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but I have already checked this, and the icon does not appear there.

Comment: Bummer. I do have one more idea for you; I'll put it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the icon you're seeing?

[image: BroadcastMyself]

WARNING: I don't know anything about this app, whether it is benign or malignant. I was just looking for something that might match what you described since you mentioned "broadcast" and a red icon.

It's from an app called Broadcast or BroadcastMyself

[Broadcast® V0.3 app for pc](http://www.appsforpc.me/Broadcast%C2%AE/1470572)

[image: Broadcast Myself icon]

Comment: I don't think so, checked and I don't have this installed.